# VS Debug / Release execution speed and code skiped in C++ console program

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

1. When I compile C++ (console program) with "release" instead of "debug", it seems that empty loops (this might seem weird, but it's important for testing purposes) get just skipped. Is this some compiler setting, because when building with "debug" they won't get skipped, but rather get executed like expected.
2. Is there any loss in execution speed when exporting with "debug" instead of "release"?

Solution:
There is an optimization tab in the configuration properties of the compiler settings.

Optimization - Custom

Prefer Size or Speed - Prefer fast code

Optimization of the whole program -  Yes(/GL)

Comment: You should really add a language tag. Generally speaking "*empty loops ... get just skipped*" is entirely expected, and any optimizing compiler will do that. Debug builds usually disable all optimizations, so they *may* preserve useless code, but that's not guaranteed.

Comment: @dxiv I am sorry that I forgot this, I am relatively new to this. That means, that I can disable the code skip in the settings? I'll try it later, thx for the respond

Comment: You could try to turn off optimizations and hope the compiler doesn't optimize those loops out. But that's not guaranteed to happen, and it's the wrong answer to whatever problem you hope to solve, anyway. Keep in mind that a C++ compiler does not necessarily translate your source code to machine assembly line by line. What it does is generate machine code that behaves *the same as* your source code according to the language definition. This [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) means that an empty loop which has no observable effect can always be eliminated.

Comment: Thank you, In the compiler settings (I guess) there is a tab with Optimization, and it was set to max speed on Release and disabled with Debug. Now I changed somecustom settings under and it works! It's now optimized with speed, but does not skip empty loops :D

Comment: How does it matter for testing purposes?  If there is some test code inside that loop it would not be skipped.

Comment: There is not code inside, testing for pure execution speed of empty loops

Comment: Don't use empty loops to program delays. They are not suitable dor this purpose. If you need a delay, call an OS API that provides this service.

Comment: If you need to measure performance of an empty loop, here's your answer. Empty loops are executed instantly, as if by magic. Enter this data point to your spreadsheet and move on. If you want to measure performance of a meaningful workload, just provide some kind of meaningful workload and measure it.

Comment: With my mesurement it seems that empty loops get executed at the speed of your core frequency so that means (for me) that are about 3.5 Billion a second (in C)

Comment: Unoptimised builds are not designed for performance, therefore it is pointless to measure their performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

You either change the "debug" or "release" compiler settings or just create your own compiler [settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/working-with-project-properties?view=msvc-160). In the compiler settings under the optimization tab you can choose custom settings for the optimization where you can disable code skipping by disabling to prefer execution speed, or just disable optimization at all (not recommended).

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.